# ¿Por qué la conexión con el motor falla con gpiozero?

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, pycharm

En el siguiente trozo de código hago una conexión con mi raspberry desde pycharm.  **ledon** hace la conexión correctamente y me permite apagar/encender el led corriendo el programa desde windows.

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk


from gpiozero import LED, Motor
from gpiozero.pins.pigpio import PiGPIOFactory


factory = PiGPIOFactory(host='192.168.31.150')
ledon = LED(17, pin_factory=factory)
ledon.on()
motor1 = Motor(23, 24, pwm=True, pin_factory=factory)
motor1.forward()
```

En el caso de **motor1** da el siguiente error no acabo de entender que es lo que falta, he probado ha instalar el package RPi.GPIO en pycharm pero da error no hay manera

```
C:\Users\calde\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\gpiozero\devices.py:288: PinFactoryFallback: Falling back from rpigpio: No module named 'RPi'
  warnings.warn(
C:\Users\calde\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\gpiozero\devices.py:288: PinFactoryFallback: Falling back from lgpio: No module named 'lgpio'
  warnings.warn(
C:\Users\calde\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\gpiozero\devices.py:288: PinFactoryFallback: Falling back from rpio: No module named 'RPIO'
  warnings.warn(
C:\Users\calde\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\gpiozero\devices.py:288: PinFactoryFallback: Falling back from pigpio: failed to connect to localhost:8888
  warnings.warn(
C:\Users\calde\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\gpiozero\devices.py:288: PinFactoryFallback: Falling back from native: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/proc/cpuinfo'
  warnings.warn(
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "P:\PROYECTOS\RCC\main.py", line 29, in <module>
    motor1 = Motor(23, 24, pwm=True, pin_factory=factory)
  File "C:\Users\calde\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\gpiozero\devices.py", line 108, in __call__
    self = super(GPIOMeta, cls).__call__(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\calde\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\gpiozero\output_devices.py", line 1223, in __init__
    super(Motor, self).__init__(_order=devices.keys(), **devices)
  File "C:\Users\calde\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\gpiozero\mixins.py", line 85, in __init__
    super(SourceMixin, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\calde\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\gpiozero\devices.py", line 432, in __init__
    super(CompositeDevice, self).__init__(pin_factory=pin_factory)
  File "C:\Users\calde\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\gpiozero\devices.py", line 250, in __init__
    Device.pin_factory = Device._default_pin_factory()
  File "C:\Users\calde\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\gpiozero\devices.py", line 291, in _default_pin_factory
    raise BadPinFactory('Unable to load any default pin factory!')
gpiozero.exc.BadPinFactory: Unable to load any default pin factory!
```

El error al instalar el modulo:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Tienes que publicar un código completo, que podamos copiar para probar.

Comment: @CandidMoe He actualizado el código, eso es todo con el LED no hay problema hace la conexión y puedo utilizarlo

Comment: Me llama la atención que funcione el LED pero no el Motor, como si `factory` hubiera quedado en `None`. Desgraciadamente mi Pi se quemó. Suerte.

Comment: https://gpiozero.readthedocs.io/en/stable/remote_gpio.html#environment-variables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Al final lo he solucionado de esta manera:

```
import os
from time import sleep
os.environ["PIGPIO_ADDR"] = "192.168.31.150"
os.environ["GPIOZERO_PIN_FACTORY"] = "pigpio"

ledon = LED(17)
motor1 = Motor(23,24)
```

Hay que setear las variables del sistema que hacen referencia a **pigpio** porqué si no cogerá localhost por defecto. Y lo que queremos es conectarnos a la ip de la raspberry pi desde un pc remoto, corriendo el programa en el remoto no en la raspberry.